# convert pandas dataframe to dictionary

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary

I have a pandas dataframe named past_trend which looks like this

```
   created       moans  thanks
0  2016-12-16     0      0
1  2016-12-17     0      0
2  2016-12-18     0      0
3  2016-12-19     0      2
4  2016-12-20     6      0
5  2016-12-21     0      0
6  2016-12-22     0      2
```

and I'm trying to convert this to a dictionary which looks something like this

```
{"moans": [
        ["16 Dec", 0],
        ["17 Dec", 0],
        ["18 Dec", 0],
        ["19 Dec", 2],
        ["20 Dec", 0],
        ["21 Dec", 0],
        ["22 Dec", 2]
    ],
    "thanks": [
        ["16 Dec", 0],
        ["17 Dec", 0],
        ["18 Dec", 0],
        ["19 Dec", 0],
        ["20 Dec", 6],
        ["21 Dec", 0],
        ["22 Dec", 0]
    ]}
```

the date format does not have to be rigidly like the one shown above, it could be as is also. Thing is when I use the to_dict function I'm getting an output which looks like this

```
{'created': {0: Timestamp('2016-12-16 00:00:00'),
1: Timestamp('2016-12-17 00:00:00'),
2: Timestamp('2016-12-18 00:00:00'),
3: Timestamp('2016-12-19 00:00:00'),
4: Timestamp('2016-12-20 00:00:00'),
5: Timestamp('2016-12-21 00:00:00'),
6: Timestamp('2016-12-22 00:00:00')},
'moans': {0: 0, 1: 0, 2: 0, 3: 0, 4: 6, 5: 0, 6: 0},
'thanks': {0: 0, 1: 0, 2: 0, 3: 2, 4: 0, 5: 0, 6: 2}}
```

so I converted the group types(moan,thanks) into a list and am trying to iterate over that. I have gotten this far, as shown below.

```
#now create the result we want
result = {}
group_types = ['moans', 'thanks']
for group in group_types:
    result[group]={[past_trend['created'],past_trend[group]]}
result
```

but im getting an error

```
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it

```
{k: [[i.strftime('%d %b'), v] for i, v in s.iteritems()]
 for k, s in df.set_index('created').iteritems()}

{'moans': [['16 Dec', 0],
  ['17 Dec', 0],
  ['18 Dec', 0],
  ['19 Dec', 0],
  ['20 Dec', 6],
  ['21 Dec', 0],
  ['22 Dec', 0]],
 'thanks': [['16 Dec', 0],
  ['17 Dec', 0],
  ['18 Dec', 0],
  ['19 Dec', 2],
  ['20 Dec', 0],
  ['21 Dec', 0],
  ['22 Dec', 2]]}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's on way.

```
In [99]: {k: [[x, y] for x, y in v.items()] 
            for k, v in df.set_index('created').to_dict().iteritems()}
Out[99]:
{'moans': [['2016-12-22', 0],
  ['2016-12-20', 6],
  ['2016-12-21', 0],
  ['2016-12-19', 0],
  ['2016-12-18', 0],
  ['2016-12-17', 0],
  ['2016-12-16', 0]],
 'thanks': [['2016-12-22', 2],
  ['2016-12-20', 0],
  ['2016-12-21', 0],
  ['2016-12-19', 2],
  ['2016-12-18', 0],
  ['2016-12-17', 0],
  ['2016-12-16', 0]]}
```

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you start with your dataframe:

```
In [5]: df
Out[5]: 
     created  moans  thanks
0 2016-12-16      0       0
1 2016-12-17      0       0
2 2016-12-18      0       0
3 2016-12-19      0       2
4 2016-12-20      6       0
5 2016-12-21      0       0
6 2016-12-22      0       2
```

The easiest thing to do would be to set the index to `'created'` then use `to_dict`:

```
In [8]: d = df.set_index('created').to_dict()

In [9]: d
   Out[9]: 
   {'moans': {Timestamp('2016-12-16 00:00:00'): 0,
     Timestamp('2016-12-17 00:00:00'): 0,
     Timestamp('2016-12-18 00:00:00'): 0,
     Timestamp('2016-12-19 00:00:00'): 0,
     Timestamp('2016-12-20 00:00:00'): 6,
     Timestamp('2016-12-21 00:00:00'): 0,
     Timestamp('2016-12-22 00:00:00'): 0},
    'thanks': {Timestamp('2016-12-16 00:00:00'): 0,
     Timestamp('2016-12-17 00:00:00'): 0,
     Timestamp('2016-12-18 00:00:00'): 0,
     Timestamp('2016-12-19 00:00:00'): 2,
     Timestamp('2016-12-20 00:00:00'): 0,
     Timestamp('2016-12-21 00:00:00'): 0,
     Timestamp('2016-12-22 00:00:00'): 2}}
```

If you don't want a dict of dicts, you can always do something like the following:

```
In [11]: d = {k:sorted(v.items()) for k,v in d.items()}

In [12]: d
Out[12]: 
{'moans': [(Timestamp('2016-12-16 00:00:00'), 0),
  (Timestamp('2016-12-17 00:00:00'), 0),
  (Timestamp('2016-12-18 00:00:00'), 0),
  (Timestamp('2016-12-19 00:00:00'), 0),
  (Timestamp('2016-12-20 00:00:00'), 6),
  (Timestamp('2016-12-21 00:00:00'), 0),
  (Timestamp('2016-12-22 00:00:00'), 0)],
 'thanks': [(Timestamp('2016-12-16 00:00:00'), 0),
  (Timestamp('2016-12-17 00:00:00'), 0),
  (Timestamp('2016-12-18 00:00:00'), 0),
  (Timestamp('2016-12-19 00:00:00'), 2),
  (Timestamp('2016-12-20 00:00:00'), 0),
  (Timestamp('2016-12-21 00:00:00'), 0),
  (Timestamp('2016-12-22 00:00:00'), 2)]}
```

And if you insist on using strings instead of Timestamp objects (a bad call IMO):

```
In [13]: {k:[(str(t),e) for t,e in v] for k,v in d.items()}
Out[13]: 
{'moans': [('2016-12-16 00:00:00', 0),
  ('2016-12-17 00:00:00', 0),
  ('2016-12-18 00:00:00', 0),
  ('2016-12-19 00:00:00', 0),
  ('2016-12-20 00:00:00', 6),
  ('2016-12-21 00:00:00', 0),
  ('2016-12-22 00:00:00', 0)],
 'thanks': [('2016-12-16 00:00:00', 0),
  ('2016-12-17 00:00:00', 0),
  ('2016-12-18 00:00:00', 0),
  ('2016-12-19 00:00:00', 2),
  ('2016-12-20 00:00:00', 0),
  ('2016-12-21 00:00:00', 0),
  ('2016-12-22 00:00:00', 2)]}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot juanpa. but really needed it as a dictionary of lists, because the front end of dashboard needed to accept it in this format..